# Intel Wireless 3165 not working in Dell Inspiron 7559 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, dell, iwlwifi

I am kind of new in linux environment and I must say that I am loving it even though I am in the learning curve. I have installed Ubuntu 64 bit 18.04 LTS on my Dell Inspiron 7559 using a live ISO over the network.

Everything went like a charm but I see that my Intel 3165 wireless driver is not detected and it says manual-install = true. I did some research and performed below mentioned steps.

1. Downloaded latest Intel 3165 drivers from Intel's website in the form of tar.gz
2. Extracted them and as per the installation guide that came with it I placed the .ucode files in /lib/firmware
3. Rebooted the system

I have also tried the solution posted in of the posts and copied the 7265 ucode files and pasted them as 3165 ucode files in /lib/firmware.

Even after doing above mentioned I am not able to use wifi. Additional driver section in Update manager shows the device grayed out. Wifi works when first booted but after sometime it stops working and system never detects it back again unless I do a fresh installation, hence I am not using wifi now and using ethernet now.

Can anyone please help me with this and guide me on how to install the drivers? Below are the outputs of some commands:

```
sudo uname -a
Linux abhishek-Ubuntu64bit-7559 5.3.0-45-generic #37~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 15:58:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After Reboot:

```
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lsmod | grep iwl
iwlwifi               348160  0
cfg80211              704512  1 iwlwifi


sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
--> Returns nothing

sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
[sudo] password for abhishek: 
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000139Bsv00001028sd00000706bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

sudo lspci | grep Network
--> Returns nothing

sudo dmesg | grep iwl
--> Returns nothing

sudo cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211


sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Before Reboot:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:05:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d00003165sv00008086sd00004410bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
model    : Wireless 3165
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free

sudo lspci | grep Network
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)

sudo cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

sudo ls -ltr /etc/modprobe.d
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  156 Jul 30  2015 blacklist-modem.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2507 Jul 30  2015 alsa-base.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  347 Jan 28  2018 iwlwifi.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  583 Jan 28  2018 blacklist-rare-network.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  697 Jan 28  2018 blacklist-framebuffer.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  210 Jan 28  2018 blacklist-firewire.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  325 Jan 28  2018 blacklist-ath_pci.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1667 Nov 12  2018 blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  127 Oct 14 04:50 dkms.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  154 Nov 25 13:52 amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  154 Dec  2 11:23 intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Apr  4 13:09 blacklist-oss.conf -> /lib/linux-sound-base/noOSS.modprobe.conf

sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    8.225602] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.267415] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.495468] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[    8.524665] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: base HW address: dc:53:60:6d:bc:44
[    8.586743] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    8.605973] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0

sudo iwconfig
enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp5s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl returns nothing

Comment: Reboot and try again: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl ` It has to show something useful!

Comment: @chili555 I just now rebooted and ran "sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl", but it does not return any results. :(

Comment: Please add: `dmesg | grep -e wlp -e 05:00` Very mysterious problem!

Comment: @chili555 Returns nothing.

sudo dmesg | grep -e wlp -e 05:00
abhishek@abhishek-Ubuntu64bit-7559:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -e wlp
abhishek@abhishek-Ubuntu64bit-7559:~$

Comment: Ubuntu not only doesn't recognize the wireless device but, in fact, no longer even recognizes the PCI bus! Please reset the BIOS to defaults and make sure the BIOS is fully updated. Then try again: `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e 05:00` Crazy!!

Comment: @chili555 I tried what you recommended in your last comment, but unfortunately it is not working. I switched to Manjaro 19.0.2 and I have the same problem. However when I opened a thread in their forum, I got came across a thread where the same problem was discussed and an user also created a bug in bugzilla for Intel (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201647) and this bug status says "CLOSED WILL_NOT_FIX ". This is a bug with Intel wireless 3165 driver firmware it seems. 
An expert in the Manjaro forum recommends to replace the wireless card with some other Intel card like 8265 :(